# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5

Tags: java, android

This error occurs sometimes and sometimes it works properly. I really can't understand what the problem is.

```
int length = CitiesInfos.citiesOnTheRoad.length;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, CitiesInfos.citiesOnTheRoad[i]);

    if (CitiesInfos.roadWorkArrayList.get(i)!=null)
    {
        temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, CitiesInfos.weatherArrayList.get(i).getCelcius() + ", " +
                 CitiesInfos.weatherArrayList.get(i).getWeatherStatus());
    }
    else
    {
        temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, " ");
    }
}
```

This is the line to which logCat directs. What can the problem be?

Comment: is it a loop ? show the full loop body, including code, where you increment `i`  and where you check bounds for your `i` variable

Comment: also, please change tags to (I suppose): `java` and `android`.

Comment: I edited my question. Thx

Comment: If the size is 5 then the highest index you can go to is 4.

Comment: i is looped from 0 to citiesOnTheRoad.length - 1 (correct) but you use i to index roadWorkArrayList and weatherArrayList, how are you verifying they are the correct size?

Comment: They use same values from a database, that's why they are equal as size. And as I said my app is sometimes works properly

Comment: just for logging purposes, show the size of the following info in your log and inspect it: `CitiesInfos.citiesOnTheRoad.length` and `CitiesInfos.weatherArrayList.size()`.

Comment: a/ there is nothing in your code that demonstrate that `roadWorkArrayList` has at least the as much items as `citiesOnTheRoad`. Same goes for `weatherArrayList`. b/ There is nothing in your code that demonstrate that those are not modified from another thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

increment variable `i` loops from 0 to `citiesOnTheRoad.length - 1`, however, you also use i as an index to two other `ArrayList` variables:  `weatherArrayList` and `roadWorkArrayList`, how are you certain they are the correct size?

I added a check that will prevent the crash you are receiving, but I caution you to take a closer look at your code instead of putting this band-aid on it.

```
    int length = CitiesInfos.citiesOnTheRoad.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, CitiesInfos.citiesOnTheRoad[i]);
        if(i < CitiesInfos.roadWorkArrayList.size() 
            && i < CitiesInfos.weatherArrayList.size() 
            && CitiesInfos.roadWorkArrayList.get(i)!=null)
        {
            temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, CitiesInfos.weatherArrayList.get(i).getCelcius() + ", " + CitiesInfos.weatherArrayList.get(i).getWeatherStatus());
        }
        else
        {
            temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, " ");
        }
}
```

Comment: I check control variable for all ArrayLists and it seems OK. Is there any way to finish first "temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, CitiesInfos.weatherArrayList.get(i).getCelcius() + ", " + CitiesInfos.weatherArrayList.get(i).getWeatherStatus());" part first, and then work for second one. For each loop cycle. I think about runOnUIThread but it needs final variables.

Answer (score 3):

As James Wierzba has mentioned, you are using the same control variable for the array lists in the loop and that is your problem.

You need to ensure that there are enough items before you try to retrieve an element.

**A few suggestions:**

it seems you are storing related data in two arrays, you are better of grouping this data together inside a class e.g. City.

You could then have the cities on the road array contain a number of city objects each storing information about the weather in that city.

I would also suggest that you do not have your arrays as public variables, you should have them as private or protected and use getters/setters to access them.